# Cursor fica do tamanho do Height do input

Tags: css

Tenho um form e dentro dele inputs.
O HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="nomeForm" name="nomeForm" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Nome';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Nome')this.value='';" value="Nome">
```

O CSS

```
.contatoForm input {
    width: 560px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-family:"OpenSansLight";
    font-size: 15pt;
    color: #20253a;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-color: #f7f7f8;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

O problema:
O cursor, quando se clica dentro do input, fica gigante, eu não acho legal, hehe. Isso acontece no Chrome.

Se eu usar `padding-top` ao invés de `line-height`, fica legal, mas não sei se seria a melhor solução.

Tem que funcionar no **IE8** também.

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução rápida e fácil é usar `line-height: normal` ao invés de fixar um tamanho de linha ([fonte original dessa solução aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3843436/2896619)). Testei e funcionou bem no Chrome ([JSFiddle aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/4qvzb6v7/)).

Comment: Então, o `line-height: normal` não funciona no IE8, por isso costumo informar em `px` o tamanho.

Comment: Foi mals. Como não tinha limitação de versão na sua pergunta, nem prestei atenção nesse detalhe. :)

Comment: Que isso, de boas, esqueci de informar, valeu a ajuda :D